# Use linq to check if an string value is in string array or List in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, c#-4.0, lambda

I use the followings to check the array or List is Included a value:

```
string[] Names= { /* */};
string target = "";

if(Array.IndexOf(Names, target) > -1)
  //Do
```

So is there any linq command to check it?

Comment: Why do you need a lambda expression?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Do you mean a Linq method?

If so, there is one:

```
Names.Contains(target)
```

Note there is no need for any lambda here.

Comment: @Killercam : actually, I suspect the compiler would generate the same IL as Names.Any( s => s == target ) because there is no better way to find a match in an Array. If Names was not an array but some other kind of IEnumerable with a more efficient search algorithm, contains would be more efficient indeed.

Answer (score 11):

```
   Names.Any( s => s == target );
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
Names.Any(n => Equals(n, target));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] Names= { /* */};
string target = "";

if(Names.Contains(target))
  //Do
```